# dynamic choice in flow not showing value

Tags: flow

I have a vf page that uses a flow.  The flow has a field with a choice type of dropdown list and it pulls records from a custom object.  Recently one of the values stopped displaying in the dropdown list.  The only filter is Id does not equal `{!$GlobalConstant.EmptyString}`.  I've queried the records and the value shows up in the query.  I see all the other values in the dropdown list, just not this one value?  What would stop one value from showing up in the dropdown list within a flow?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the value not displaying for all users, including the system admin profile?

Comment: yes, I'm a system administrator and I can't see the value.  I can see all the other values, just not this one value.  I can query the object and see all the values.  I can even see old records that has used the value and it displays.  It is only in the flow dropdown list that is not showing the value.  I can't make sense of why the value isn't showing up?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your dynamic picklist setup?

Comment: I figured out the issue.  There is a hard limit of 200.